# g++ and clang++ different behaviour with alias template

Tags: c++, c++11, template-specialization, type-alias

Trying to respond to another question, I've written the following code that behave different in g++ (6.3.0) and in clang++ (3.8.1)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename>
struct foo
 { };

template <typename T>
using alias = foo<T>;

template <template <typename...> class, template <typename...> class>
struct bar : public std::false_type
 { };

template <template <typename...> class C>
struct bar<C, C> : public std::true_type
 { };

int main()
 {
   // g++     print 1
   // clang++ print 0
   std::cout << bar<foo, alias>::value << std::endl;
 }
```

g++ prints `1` (that is: activate the specialization `bar` struct, that is treat `foo` and `alias` as equals) and clang++ prints `0` (that is: activate the generic `bar` struct, that is treat `foo` and `alias` as differents).

The question, as usual, is: who's right? g++ or clang++ ?

Comment: Looks like a compiler bug in clang to me

Comment: clang 4.0.0 and gcc 7.1.1 still give the same results

Comment: @Darklighter doesn't seem to be working for me https://wandbox.org/permlink/NNpfctbYEU5l8SdM

Comment: If I remember correctly, wording has changed in this regard, so it might depend of interpretation and/or standard. For C++17, it should be identical for your sample.

Comment: @Curious I’m sorry that I was confusing, I just wanted to add that the behavior doesn’t change with the current releases of gcc and clang regarding the results presented in the question.

Comment: [CWG 1286](http://wg21.link/cwg1286)